# Method for storing a user's website privileges and querying in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

What I have:

I have a column in my table called `privileges` that stores a string of privileges for a user. (-1 = owner, 0 = admin, 1 = moderate comments, etc.) So I would have string like this in sql: `1,2,3`.

The problem:

If I wanted to select all users that are admins AND moderators, it becomes a little tricky with `LIKE` conditions. Right now, If I want an admin, I just cycle through all the users search for 1 (using PHP - inefficient).

I am looking for a solution that is easily 'plugged' by plugin developers and is easily query-ed. My solution works, but if the users were to grow to hundreds, it could take awhile cycling through all them repeatedly just to find a certain privilege.

Does anyone have a better method or thoughts on this?

Comment: you need to use relational database [user]-to-[roles]... You are saying looping with PHP is inefficient, what about LIKE??? To achieve what you want you must use wildcards at the start of LIKE queries... worst way of doing it. Look into ACL.

Comment: @Alex - I'm definitely a novice at mySQL, but I assumed transferring data back and forth would be less efficient than having a slow query using `LIKE`.

Comment: you can create a view based on your current table structure in which you can split all user types and combine multiple queries with `UNION`. Then query the view for specific type (e.g. `WHERE type=1`). Slow query but least amount of data transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    privileges
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(0, privilege)
        AND FIND_IN_SET(1, privilege)
```

You will have a faster query if you normalize your table (create an additional table `user_privileges` with separate record per privilege). This way you could run:

```
SELECT  user
FROM    user_privileges
WHERE   privilege IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY
        user
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

and this could use an index on `privilege`.

You may also consider storing the privileges in a native `SET` datatype.

Comment: What happens if I have a privilege flag that is greater than 9? `FIND_IN_SET(1,privilege)` would return something if I had `2,3,10`, no?

Comment: @Jason: no, it won't. Just run `SELECT FIND_IN_SET(1, '2,3,10')`

Comment: I was hoping I could stay away from adding another table. But it seems like I don't have any other elegant solution. Quick question, say I queried the User database, how do append every privilege into another column before return the row? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jason: not clear what exactly do you want to do. Could you please post a sample dataset and a desired output of the query?

Comment: I added a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540942/combining-mysql-tables-into-one-row It is a little more complex than this, but along the same lines.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you usea a Table like Priviledge , that holds an id and a name. Then add a many to many UserPriviledge table that related used_id and priviledge_id, so then looking for a users its as simple as making an INNER_JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Your table should be normalized as suggested by guiman. Per Wikipedia: Normalized tables are suitable for general-purpose querying. This means any queries against these tables, including future queries whose details cannot be anticipated, are supported. In contrast, tables that are not normalized lend themselves to some types of queries, but not others.