# Combining mySQL tables into one row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables that are linked.

`images` Table

```
cid     link
=======================
1       something.jpg
2       else.jpg
```

`terms` Table

```
cid     term         is_attr
================================
1      Location     0
2      Caption      1
3      Camera Lens  0
```

`tags` Table

```
cid      Name          term_id
==============================
1       somewhere      1
2       BFE            1
3       A word         2
```

`linked_tags` Table

```
cid    photo_id     tag_id
==========================
1      1            1
2      1            2
3      1            3
```

if a Term `is_attr == 1` the image should only have ONE entry in the `linked_tags` table for that term.

If I were to query the image table and get the tags at the same time, how would I do that?

I'd like to have (something) this returned:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
cid      |link              |attributes        |tags                |
=========|==================|==================|====================|
1        |something.jpg     |__________________|____________________| 
         |                  ||term    |value  |||term    |value    ||
         |                  ||========|=======|||========|=========||
         |                  ||caption |A word |||Location|somewhere||
         |                  ||        |       |||Location|BFE      ||
```

This is what I am looking for (PHP side):

```
//Row 1
array(
  'link' => "something.jpg",
  'attributes' => array('caption'=>"A word"),
  'tags' => array('Location'=>array('somewhere','BFE'))
);
//Notice 'caption' points to a string and 'location' points to an array
//Row 2
array(
  'link' => "else.jpg",
  'attributes' => array(),
  'tags' => array()
);
// OR
array(
  'link' => "else.jpg"
);
// OR
array(
  'link' => "else.jpg",
  'attributes' => array('caption'=>""),
  'tags' => array();
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM    image i
JOIN    tag
ON      tag.image_id = i.id
GROUP BY
        i.id
```

**Update:**

Tabular format assumes same number of columns in each record, all having the same type across the records.

Your task is best done in three queries:

```
SELECT  cid, link
FROM    image
WHERE   cid = 1
```

(cid and link)

```
SELECT  t.name, tag.name
FROM    linked_tags lt
JOIN    tags
ON      tags.cid = lt.tag_id
JOIN    terms t
ON      t.cid = tags.term_id
WHERE   lt.photo_id = 1
        AND  t.is_attr = 1
```

(attributes)

```
SELECT  t.name, tag.name
FROM    linked_tags lt
JOIN    tags
ON      tags.cid = lt.tag_id
JOIN    terms t
ON      t.cid = tags.term_id
WHERE   lt.photo_id = 1
        AND  t.is_attr = 0
```

(tags)

Comment: Where does the Term table come in to play?

Comment: @Jason: your question was: "If I were to query the image table and get the tags at the same time", it does not mention any terms :) Could you please post the desired output in tabular format?

Comment: @Quassnoi - yes. I went back and looked at my tables and realized what I have is different than I put anyway. I actually have 4 tables. Whoops. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Am I missing something? It thinks tags.cid is a table. I am getting this error: `Table 'tags.cid' doesn't exist`

Comment: Nevermind, you've got an error. Fix your first `JOIN` and add `ON`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'd want to the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

edit:

phooey. Quassnoi beat me to the punch. Just as a warning: GROUP_CONCAT's output is length limited (usually 1024 bytes by default), but you can override it with the `group_concat_max_length` run-time setting.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or does this just need a few LEFT JOINs?

```
$query = 'SELECT images.cid, images.link, terms.term, tags.name, terms.is_attr FROM images LEFT JOIN linked_tags ON images.cid = linked_tags.photo_id LEFT JOIN tags ON linked_tags.tag_id = tags.cid LEFT JOIN terms ON tags.term_id = terms.cid WHERE 1 ORDER BY images.cid';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The result set will give you multiple rows for each image, and you can use PHP to parse the data into whatever format you need like this.

```
$image_list = array();
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // fetch mysql rows until there are no more
    if (!isset($image_list[$line['cid']]) { // checks to see if we have created this image array row yet
        // if not, create new image in image array using cid as the key
        $image_list[$line['cid']] = array('link' => $line['link'], 'attributes' => array(), 'tags' => array());
    }
    if ($line['term'] != null) { // if there are no linked attributes or tags, move on to the next image leaving both arrays empty, otherwise...
        if ($line['is_attr']) {
            // if attribute row, add attribute using term as key
            $image_list[$line['cid']]['attributes'][$line['term']] = $line['name'];
        } else {
            // if tag row, add tag using term as key
            $image_list[$line['cid']]['tags'][$line['term']] = $line['name']; 
        }
    }
}
```

If I am reading you correctly, this should output exactly what you are looking for.